# (Windows 10) Unable to use Anaconda Prompt - AttributeError: module 'colorama' has no attribute 'init'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, windows-10, attributeerror

When I open Anaconda, I am unable to do anything. When I type a command, I end up getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jenni\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\jenni\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 145, in main
    init_loggers()
  File "C:\Users\jenni\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 56, in init_loggers
    from ..gateways.logging import initialize_logging, set_verbosity
  File "C:\Users\jenni\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\logging.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ..common.io import attach_stderr_handler
  File "C:\Users\jenni\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\io.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .._vendor.tqdm import tqdm
  File "C:\Users\jenni\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\tqdm\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._tqdm import tqdm
  File "C:\Users\jenni\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\tqdm\_tqdm.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._utils import _supports_unicode, _environ_cols_wrapper, _range, _unich, \
  File "C:\Users\jenni\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\tqdm\_utils.py", line 31, in <module>
    colorama.init()
AttributeError: module 'colorama' has no attribute 'init'
```

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling colorama, but I can't do so without Anaconda. Has anyone encountered this issue before? I've only seen one specific instance on here and it involves uninstalling.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem after uninstalling/re-installing Python & Anaconda.

From the [miniconda troubleshooting page](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#attributeerror-or-missing-getproxies):

> This can be caused by an old version of `requests` or by having the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable set.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Update `requests` and be sure `PYTHONPATH` is not set:
>
> 1. Run `conda info -a` to show the requests version and various environment variables such as `PYTHONPATH`.
> 2. Update the `requests` version with `pip install -U requests`.
> 3. Clear `PYTHONPATH`:
>
>    - On Windows, clear it the environment variable settings.
>    - On macOS and Linux, clear it by removing it from the bash profile and restarting the shell.

Comment: The suggested solution from the troubleshooting page is for a different error, viz. *"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getproxies'"*

Comment: So, instead of upgrading `requests`, we need to run `pip install --upgrade colorama`.  Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72871374).