# AttributeError: module 'colorama' has no attribute 'init'

Tags: django, apache

I have Python version 3.8 and trying to deploy Django model to Apache2 server and getting this error. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by upgrading colorama version.